# Can I load multiple libraries using google.load(...)?

Tags: ajax, javascript

On Google code [playgorund](http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground), I tried to load multiple library like below

```
google.load("jquery", "1");
google.load("mootools", "1.2.1");
```

But it breaks the code, why ? Thanks

**EDIT:** In the left hand pane in playground, I select Library and then jquery, its runs just fine but when I also add mootools in the code, it won't work and I don't see any message even when clicking on debug.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't provide any information *what* breaks, all I can say is: It should work. Next time, post an error message or something similar.

[EDIT] Maybe there is a bug in `google.load()`. I suggest to set a breakpoint and to step through the function to see where it hangs.

Comment: Edited question with some details. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Do you see any output in the browser's console?

Comment: No, its just trying to load something indefinitely. I will try to check the error on my local machine and will paste the error here.